# JSON url parse returns NaN in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have created a URL Shortener web service, which returns JSON, if correct parameters (`url`) is passed.

Now, since I am learning Node.js, I am trying to create a Node.js wrapper for parsing the data and printing them in console (for now).

I am using `http` and `request` module for parsing the JSON data which I received from the url response.

This is my code that prints the data :

```
var request = require('request');
var http = require('http');

var url = process.argv[2];
var apiUrl = "http://shtr.ml/stats-api.php?url=" + url;

http.get(apiUrl,function(res){
var body = '';
res.on('data',function(chunk)
{
    body += chunk;
});

res.on('end',function(){
    const resp = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
    if(resp.message.toString() == "Success")
    {
        console.log("Short URL : ",resp.short-url);
        console.log("Long URL : ",resp.long-url);
        console.log("Creation Date : ",resp.created);
        console.log("Total Clicks : ",resp.clicks);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Stats Error !!");
    }
});
}).on('error',function(e){
    console.log("Got an error ",e);
});
```

Now, following is my code output :

```
C:\node-shtr-module>node index.js http://shtr.ml/ZVFWdk


{"message":"Success","short-url":"http://shtr.ml/ZVFWdk","long-url":"https://github.com/beingadityak/dot-net-mysql","created":"2016-09-27 22:58:06","clicks":"21"}

Short URL :  NaN
Long URL :  NaN
Creation Date :  2016-09-27 22:58:06
Total Clicks :  21
```

Why is the `resp.short-url` returning `NaN` even though the JSON contains the URL ? Please help.

As always, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

access it using
`resp['short-url']` and `resp['long-url']`

Comment: what's the difference ?

Comment: we can't create variable, function name using dash. while on object notation we can create key using dash but we can only access it using [] way. it's a specification.